# jmap -F(force) option doesn't work

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

I was diagnosing a JVM problem with `jmap` command:

```
jmap -histo:live <pid>
```

and got the following prompt:

```
<pid>: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

Then I issued `jmap` again with `-F` option:

```
jmap -F -histo:live <pid>
```

and got the `jmap` usage prompt. It seems that I typed wrong command options. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:live` is not supported with `-F`. Try

```
jmap -F -histo <pid>
```